# Flutter private methods function

Tags: flutter, private-methods

How to change it to private method? I dont know how

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initPackageInfo();
  }

   Future<void> _initPackageInfo() async {
    final info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    setState(() {
      _packageInfo = info;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

To make a function private in dart, we have to use a '_' before function name,

so your `_initPackageInfo`  is a private function.